# MediaPlayer returning wrong mouse position

Tags: delphi, mouse

I've run into a strange problem with the MediaPlayer component
that appears to be a bug with either the API or Delphi.
I display the video directly on the Form2 canvas and allow
the user to zoom and drag the video within the window. 
I use the Form2.MouseDown and MouseUp events to drag.

The drag was behaving erratically and I traced the problem
to inconsistent use of the window coordinates in the events.
An MPG or WMV video (compressed) will report the MouseDown
coordinates relative to the video, but the MouseUp relative
to the form.  An AVI video (uncompressed) will report both
relative to the form.

I'm using Delphi XE3 with Windows 7.
Has anyone else encountered this anomaly, and how can I 
get consistent X,Y coordinates?

Added 7/20:

I don't know what MCVE means, but I added some code in case someone 
wants to try and duplicate the problem.
Label1 & Label2 report the mouse coordinates, and if the video is moved
out of the (0,0) position then the coordinates will jump as the mouse 
crosses into or out of the video.  It should not do that, it should
always report coordinates relative to the window, not the video.
FormMouseUp will always report relative to the window.
FormMouseDown and FormMouseMove jump back and forth.

```
procedure TForm1.MFLoadFileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.Display := Form2;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; 
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(X); {diag}
  Label2.Caption := IntToStr(Y); {diag}
  VidLoc := Form1.MediaPlayer1.DisplayRect;
  mX := X;   mY := Y;
  MouseDown := True;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; 
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(X); {diag}
  Label2.Caption := IntToStr(Y); {diag}
end;

procedure TForm2.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; 
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var  VL : tRect;
begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(X); {diag}
  Label2.Caption := IntToStr(Y); {diag}
  if (MouseDown and Form1.Loaded) then begin
    VL := VidLoc;
    VL.Left := VidLoc.Left - mX + X;
    VL.Top  := VidLoc.Top  - mY + Y;
    Form1.MediaPlayer1.DisplayRect := VL;
    Form1.MediaPlayer1.Step;
  end;
  MouseDown := False;
end;
```

Comment: Please give us an MCVE for this

Comment: I can duplicate that. You don't need two forms and all the code in mouse events to duplicate, but never mind. Anyway, all I can tell is that VCL does not seem tho have any part in this. `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is sent with coordinates relative to the "ActiveMovie Window" although the message is destined to the form. I suggest you to use a panel or something to move around.

Comment: The same thing happens with a Panel.

Comment: @Humanoid1000 [On MCVE](http://bit.ly/1k85x5c). Please do the minimal effort.

Comment: @Humanoid - You're not modifying the displayrect of the media player when you're using a panel, right?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, moving the video in a panel doesn't work, but moving the panel did.
I didn't want to do that because it requires keeping track of too many objects, but it'll have to do.
Moving the panel uses the same code as above, but with other assorted properties.

Comment: It's not odd at all, the player is always at (0, 0) in its parent. That's why I suggested *".. a panel or something to move around"*.